# How to do length arithmetic when one argument is returned from a function?

Tags: sass

a: Adding two lengths with units are ok.
b: the function returns a length with unit.
c: adding the result of this function to a length with the same unit is not ok.

```
@function px2vw($px) {
  @return #{$px / 1200 * 100}vw;
}

.abc {
  a: 50vw + 2vw;
  b: px2vw(600);
  c: px2vw(600) + 2vw;
}
```

---

```
// output    
.abc {
  a: 52vw;
  b: 50vw;
  c: 50vw2vw;    // bad
}



// want
.abc {
  a: 52vw;
  b: 50vw;
  c: 52vw;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math in example c isn't able to be properly performed because Sass is interpolating that `52vw` as a string rather than 52 viewport width units.  This is because you're manually adding the letters `vw` to the function's output.

Instead, you can convert to vw units in the function like so. This will have your desired output:

```css
@function px2vw($px) {
  @return $px / 1200 * 100vw;
}

.abc {
  a: 50vw + 2vw;
  b: px2vw(600);
  c: px2vw(600) + 2vw;
}
```

Returns:

```
.abc {
  a: 52vw;
  b: 50vw;
  c: 52vw;
}
```

Comment: This is correct. I would add parens for readability: @return ($px / 1200) * 100vw;